# WARN/SoundPool sample 2 not READY

Tags: android

SoundPool works properly on Android 1.6 but when I run on 2.1 in the Emulator I am getting a "sample 2 not READY" error message everytime I try to play a sound.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SoundPool on Android 2.0 and higher works only with OGG Vorbis files.  If you're using MP3 or the like, they won't decode.

Comment: SoundPool on Android 2.0 and higher will work with other encodings, depends on the MediaPlayer's ability to decode.

Comment: Nonsense, I have a soundpool on android 2.3 and 3.0 that uses mp3's. Maybe android 2.1 doesn't work? I can't verify that.

Comment: I also agree that is nonsense. I have only ever used mp3s with SoundPool and it works just fine from Froyo to Honeycomb

Answer (score 3):

On my device just wait a few seconds for the audio stream to be ready.

Or use this, `OnLoadCompleteListener`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener.html

I can play ogg/wav/mp3...

`SoundPool` can create different decoders/players for each media type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
public void loadSound (String strSound, int stream) {
     boolean loaded = false;
     mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                mSoundPool.play(stream, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, LOOP_1_TIME, 1f);
            }
        });
    try {
          stream= mSoundPool.load(aMan.openFd(strSound), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```