# EditText text use as filename

Tags: android, android-edittext, soundpool

I have application that will search for song on external storage and play it by clicking a button. I use `String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), "FILENAME");` and it works fine if i type something like song.mp3...I tried to use `EditText.getText().toString();` 
except "FILENAME" and it doesnt work. This is my code in OnCreate:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
            String string = et.getText().toString();
        sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), string);
        mSoundId = sp.load(path, 1);
```

And LogCat says `11-07 14:26:39.909: W/SoundPool(12627):   sample 1 not READY

BUT if I input `et.setText("SongName");` it works fine.. I want to type something in edittext and then use it as filename! 
Thanks
`

Comment: In OnCreate is there any event happening like Button Click or something. Then on button click you get text from edittext.

Comment: Only this is in my button click public void button1(View view) {

  if (mStreamId != 0) {
   sp.stop(mStreamId);
  }
  mStreamId = sp.play(mSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in OnCreate:

```
mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1); 
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    public void onLoadComplete (SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
        mStreamId = soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}
```

Then in your onClick do:

```
public void yourOnClickMethod(View view) { 
    if (mStreamId != 0) { 
        mSoundPool.stop(mStreamId); 
    } 

    String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), EditText.getText().toString());
    mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(path, 1); 
}
```

Comment: 11-07 15:07:01.659: W/SoundPool(14064):   sample 1 not READY

Comment: check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116910/warn-soundpool-sample-2-not-ready) and [SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener.html). It takes a while for the sample to be ready.

Answer (score 0):

OnCreate will only be called one time for each lifetime of the Activity. So OnCreate is used to initialize UI. So it does not get the change on EditText. Have a button. On Click get the data from edittext. That should solve your problem.

Comment: I did like this   if (mStreamId != 0) {
   sp.stop(mStreamId);
  }
     String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), mEditText.getText().toString());
      mSoundId = sp.load(path, 1);
      mStreamId = sp.play(mSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f); 
 }    And i am getting same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202510/soundpool-sample-not-ready. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786314/android-2-2-soundpool-sample-0-is-not-ready. Have a look a these links.

Comment: if i type in edittext filename that doesnt exist on my external storage then i get something like this 11-07 15:24:35.219: E/SoundPool(14487): error loading /mnt/sdcard/dub.mp3
But if i put dub2.mp3 that exists i get 11-07 15:24:35.219: E/SoundPool(14487): error loading /mnt/sdcard/dub.mp3
and everytime i click the button again it gives sample 2 not ready..next time sample 3 not ready...